# Flutter error setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter

I want to set pin in `PinFieldAutoFill` using [sms_autofill](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill)

I am facing 2 **issues**

**1- setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.**

**2- Each child must be laid out exactly once.**

Kindly let me know how to solve that issues.

Here is my code

```
class _SetPinScreenState extends State<SetPinScreen> {
  bool obscureText = true;
  TextEditingController _otpTextController = TextEditingController();
  bool isPinSet = false;
  String pin = '', confirmedPin = '';

  void _updatePin(String val) {
    if (pin.length != 4)
      pin = val;
    else
      confirmedPin = val;
    if (pin.length == 4) {
      setState(() {
        isPinSet = true;
      });
      
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _otpTextController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isButtonEnabled = (pin == confirmedPin);
    return MainTemplate(
      isFloatingButtonVisible: true,
      isFloatingActionButtonDisabled: isButtonEnabled,
      floatingButtonAction: () {
        if (isButtonEnabled) {
          print("Floating action button pressed");
        }
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                isPinSet
                    ? 'Re-enter your PIN code to Confirm'
                    : 'Set PIN for your Card Ending With XXXX',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 30),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Center(
              child: PinFieldAutoFill(
                decoration: UnderlineDecoration(
                  textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                  gapSpace: 8,
                  obscureStyle: ObscureStyle(isTextObscure: obscureText),
                  lineHeight: 1.2,
                  colorBuilder:
                      PinListenColorBuilder(Colors.black, Colors.grey.shade400),
                ),
                onCodeChanged: _updatePin,
                codeLength: 4,
               
                autoFocus: true,
                controller: _otpTextController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(
              'Pin must be at least 4 digits. It must not be single digits like'
              ' 1111 or digits in numerical order such as 1234',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: for your first issue, you can use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` to solve it

Comment: kindly write the code for this how to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your first issue, add your `setState` code into `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` block like below

```
  void _updatePin(String val) {
    if (pin.length != 4)
      pin = val;
    else
      confirmedPin = val;
    if (pin.length == 4) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
        setState(() {
          isPinSet = true;
        });
      })
    }
  }
```

and for your second issue, i just found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build), might be helpful

**Update**

when i run your code, i finally found what the real issue is, in re-enter mod, the `PinFieldAutoFill` will be rebuilt every time you typed a number

```
  void _updatePin(String? val) {
    if (pin.length != 4)
      pin = val ?? '';
    else
      confirmedPin = val ?? '';
    if (pin.length == 4 && !isPinSet) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
        setState(() {
          isPinSet = true;
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: i write like this but when i enter digit it change the screen to text `Re-enter your PIN code to Confirm` and here i can't type digit.

Comment: It resolve the second issue also.

Comment: but when i want to re-type my code it is not typing on `PinFieldAutoFill`

Comment: @ForStack i just updated my answer, try that code and see if it works

Comment: NO, It is not allowing me to type .

Comment: @ForStack i really found what the issue is, try the newest code, defiantly works

Comment: It works bro, Thanks, but it lose the focus, I have to click on field again to re-enter otp so how to auto focus as it before.

Comment: lose the focus? i have no idea with that, in my demo code i replace `MainTemplate` with `Container` to make the code be runnable, you may need to find it out by your self@ForStack

Comment: Hi, kindly answer of that question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76878982/how-to-clear-first-text-controller-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76878982/how-to-clear-first-text-controller-flutter)

Comment: bro, i need some help kindly response on this message

Comment: @ForStack it's been two days and you still haven't solved your issue? sorry bro, i can't help you, i have a lot of shit to do

Comment: or you can post another question contains all your issues, i will take a look if i am free

Comment: kindly take a look on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76902139/flutter-how-to-hide-and-show-floatingbutton#76902249](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76902139/flutter-how-to-hide-and-show-floatingbutton#76902249)

Comment: after setting my PIN my screen switch to Re-enter your PIN code to Confirm screen and here my PinFieldAutoFill is not accepting input after editing given answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing

```
bool isButtonEnabled = (pin == confirmedPin);
```

on onInit() function.

Answer (score 0):

Before call `setState({})` method check widget `mounted`

```
if(mounted) {
   setState(() {
     isPinSet = true;
   });
}
```