# Flutter how to hide and show FloatingButton?

Tags: flutter

**My scenario:**

User will set his PIN and here floating action button will be hide and after Set PIN, screen will switch to confirm PIN. Here I want to show floating action button. So how to do it? Due to `isFloatingButtonVisible: true,` it is showing on screen.

**Here floating action button will be hide**

[image]

**Here floating action button will be show**

[image]

**Here is my SetPinScreen**

```
class _SetPinScreenState extends State<SetPinScreen> {
  TextEditingController setPinController;

  PinValidationProvider pinValidationProvider;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setPinController = TextEditingController();
    pinValidationProvider = context.read<PinValidationProvider>();
    pinValidationProvider.resetPinValidation();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    setPinController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _validatePin(String value) {
    if (value.isNotEmpty && value.length <= 4) {
      pinValidationProvider.validatePin(value, setPinController);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MainTemplate(
      isFloatingButtonVisible: true,
      floatingButtonAction: () {},
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Consumer<PinValidationProvider>(
                builder: (context, pinProvider, child) {
                  return Text(
                    pinProvider.isPinSet
                        ? 'Re-enter your PIN code to Confirm'
                        : 'Set PIN to Activate your Finance House Card Ending With XXXX',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 30),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Center(
              child: PinFieldAutoFill(
                decoration: UnderlineDecoration(
                  textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                  gapSpace: 8,
                  lineHeight: 1.2,
                  colorBuilder:
                      PinListenColorBuilder(Colors.black, Colors.grey.shade400),
                ),
                onCodeChanged: _validatePin,
                codeLength: 4,
                cursor: Cursor(color: Colors.black, enabled: true),
                controller: setPinController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Consumer<PinValidationProvider>(
              builder: (context, provider, child) {
                final textColor = provider.isPinSet == false
                    ? provider.isInvalidPin ||
                            (!provider.isPinMatched && provider.isPinSet)
                        ? Colors.red
                        : Colors.black
                    : provider.isInvalidPin && !provider.isPinMatched
                        ? Colors.red
                        : Colors.black;

                if (!provider.isPinMatched &&
                    provider.isPinSet &&
                    setPinController.text.isNotEmpty &&
                    setPinController.text.length == 4) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'PIN does not match.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text(
                    'Pin must be at least 4 digits. It must not be single digits like'
                    ' 1111 or digits in numerical order such as 1234',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: textColor,
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**And here is my Provider**

```
class PinValidationProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isInvalidPin = false;

  bool get isInvalidPin => _isInvalidPin;

  bool isPinMatched = false;
  bool isPinSet = false;
  String pin = '';

  void validatePin(String pin, TextEditingController controller) {
    if (isPinSet) {
      matchPin(pin);
      return;
    }

    if (pin.length != 4) {
      _isInvalidPin = false;
    } else {
      _isInvalidPin = _isSimpleSequence(pin) || _isRepeatedDigit(pin);
      if (!_isInvalidPin) {
        isPinSet = true;
        this.pin = pin;
        controller.clear();
      }
    }
    _notifyListeners();
  }

  void matchPin(String pin) {
    isPinMatched = pin.length == 4 && pin == this.pin;
    _notifyListeners();
  }

  bool _isSimpleSequence(String pin) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pin.length - 1; i++) {
      int digit1 = int.parse(pin[i]);
      int digit2 = int.parse(pin[i + 1]);

      if (digit2 - digit1 == 1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  bool _isRepeatedDigit(String pin) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pin.length - 1; i++) {
      if (pin[i] == pin[i + 1]) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  void _notifyListeners() {
    Future.microtask(() {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  void resetPinValidation() {
    _isInvalidPin = false;
    isPinSet = false;
    pin = '';
    isPinMatched = false;
    _notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `bool isActionButtonVisible = false;` to `PinValidationProvider`

Then use it where ever you need to use it inside `PinValidationProvider`

Then watch its state in Widget

```
isFloatingButtonVisible: context.select((PinValidationProvider p) => p.isActionButtonVisible);
```

Comment: after adding this my `PinFieldAutoFill` is not accepting input

Comment: what do you mean by `Instead of isPinSet you can add isActionButtonVisible`

Comment: probably its because it rebuilds everytime you try to enter the pin. Then try using 
context.select<T, R>(R cb(T value)), which allows a widget to listen to only a small part of T.

Comment: Well i mean use a new variable to control the show/hide functionality.

Comment: kindly update your answer.

Comment: Well, I'm giving it my best shot to figure out what's going on here. If select does not work.. then try to debug it with debugger!

Comment: ye its is working but when i come to `Re-enter your PIN code to Confirm` screen here also i can't type in my fields

Comment: i got it but after setting my PIN my screen switch to `Re-enter your PIN code to Confirm` screen and here my `PinFieldAutoFill` is not accepting input

Comment: Is it related to my suggestion or is this a new problem?

Comment: yes due to your suggestion.

Comment: My suggestion does nothing more that to just change state of "show/hide" the floating action button. I think I answered your original question of how to "show/hide" floating button. Why the controller is working or not could be other problem with code/logic. Cheers and good luck.

Comment: BRO WHEN i remove your suggestion all works fine.